# Is it sensible to write $\bar{\bar{\alpha_1}}$?

Tags: notation

Continuing this, could you write: $\bar{\bar{\bar{\bar{\alpha_1}}}}$?

At what point do such characters become obtrusive?

Just curious. What other notations could you use, similar to this?

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of what we do for derivatives. When there are too many primes we switch to $f^{(n)}(x).$

Comment: In which context do you use this notation? What is the link with polish notation?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I was using it simply as a re-defined constant in a set of integrals. Polish notation was used as a tag, as I thought the it meant 'improving, refining' notation, by the definition of 'polish'?

Comment: It is "Polish notation," with a capital P as in then country Poland, not "polish notation" with a lower-case p as in what you do to furniture.

Comment: That is a lovely alternate pronunciation of "polish notation."

Comment: $\frac{\overline{\Xi}}{\overline{\Xi}}$

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip One.  Just 1.  Unless, of course, $\Xi = 0$, in which case it is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules on what notation is allowed.  Some forms are pretty much standard and agreed by (almost) everyone.  Some are common but not universal.  Some are quirky and individual.  You can use almost anything that you like as long as you define what you mean by it. You might want to pay attention to the readability and whether or not something nicer may be possible.

There is no central mathematical committee defining what is and is not allowed.